# CSS transition on load via JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write some code to cause a transition on load, so I basically have some jquery adding a class, `transition-left` to a div and some css that says to move left if it has the class `transition-left`. However, even though the class is being added, the transition isn't happening. I just don't know why that is the case. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#curtain-left").addClass("transition-left");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#curtain-right").addClass("transition-right");
});
```

```css
.curtain {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 0;

 /* CSS variables to prevent duplication below */
 --piece-width: 100px;
}

.curtain .content {
 /* I used flex since I'm more comfortable with that, but you can use floats if you prefer. */
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}

.curtain-panel {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;

 transition: left, right;
 transition-duration: 3s;
}

.curtain-panel.left {
 left: 0;
 justify-content: end;
}

.curtain-panel.right {
 right: 0;
}

.curtain-panel::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 1;

 background-color: #333;
}

.curtain-piece-left {
 width: var(--piece-width);
 height: auto;
 z-index: 2;
 margin: calc(100% - var(--piece-width) / 2);
}

.curtain-piece-right {
 width: var(--piece-width);
 height: auto;
 z-index: 2;
 margin: calc(var(--piece-width) / -2);
}

.transition-left{
 left: -100%;
}

.transition-right{
 right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/curtain.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
  <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Let browser know website is optimized for mobile
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="curtain">
      <div class="curtain-panel left">
        <img src="https://getsharex.com/img/ShareX_Icon_Full.ico" class="curtain-piece-left" id="curtain-left"/>
      </div>
      <div class="curtain-panel right">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/p0uNfB1-JwEd_zQfXuiMQmhxkAszQSH19V-ff6kH9_5LS4eWHsZdFQnshtP3tSLDhBuRNb2AV0RD9UGbci0bEeNeHs4Acr5RABX5TJlrQXykGCgt8wUnEgFkGLlIPm-H4Tg7oHiwfH0MnJzdrg" class="curtain-piece-right"  id="curtain-right"/>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-purple fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">a</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                  >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">b</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">c</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">d</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">e</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="container">
          <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>Template</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              Use this document as a template for other pages.<br />
              Keep in mind, Bootstrap documentation might be needed to build
              components of the other pages.
            </p>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/curtain.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you probably want window load and not document ready

Comment: What's weird is that the classes are being added, but the elements are not adjusting accordingly.

Comment: The image has the id..... image has nothing to do with the position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding it in the  wrong place. Check out my version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .curtain {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;

  /* CSS variables to prevent duplication below */
  --piece-width: 100px;
}

.curtain .content {
  /* I used flex since I'm more comfortable with that, but you can use floats if you prefer. */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.curtain-panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;

  transition: left, right;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}

.curtain-panel.left {
  left: 0;
  justify-content: end;
}

.curtain-panel.right {
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-panel::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  background-color: #333;
}

.curtain-piece-left {
  width: var(--piece-width);
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: calc(100% - var(--piece-width) / 2);
}

.curtain-piece-right {
  width: var(--piece-width);
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: calc(var(--piece-width) / -2);
}

.transition-left{
  left: -100% !important;
}

.transition-right{
  right: -100% !important;
}

    </style>

<div class="curtain">
      <div class="curtain-panel left">
        <img src="https://getsharex.com/img/ShareX_Icon_Full.ico" class="curtain-piece-left" id="curtain-left"/>
      </div>
      <div class="curtain-panel right">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/p0uNfB1-JwEd_zQfXuiMQmhxkAszQSH19V-ff6kH9_5LS4eWHsZdFQnshtP3tSLDhBuRNb2AV0RD9UGbci0bEeNeHs4Acr5RABX5TJlrQXykGCgt8wUnEgFkGLlIPm-H4Tg7oHiwfH0MnJzdrg" class="curtain-piece-right"  id="curtain-right"/>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-purple fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">a</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                  >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">b</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">c</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">d</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">e</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="container">
          <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>Template</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              Use this document as a template for other pages.<br />
              Keep in mind, Bootstrap documentation might be needed to build
              components of the other pages.
            </p>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>


<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <script>

      $(function(){
        $(".curtain-panel.left").addClass("transition-left");
        $(".curtain-panel.right").addClass("transition-right");
      })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```